# Selecting from MySQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm writing a simple user login webservice and facing a problem when selecting data from a view created in phpmyadmin.

## SQLs

These are my tables (not every column but the important ones).

account table

```
CREATE TABLE generel.account ( 
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  username VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  mail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE username (username),
  UNIQUE `mail` (mail)
);
```

userstatus table

```
CREATE TABLE game.userstatus (
  user_id INT NOT NULL ,
  is_logged_in BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY `ip` (`last_known_ip`)
);
```

with foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE userstatus
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_generel.account.id
  FOREIGN key (user_id)
  REFERENCES generel.account(user_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Please notice the sql libraries are different (generel and game).

This is the view I want to work with:

```
CREATE VIEW game.gameuser_view AS 
SELECT
  acc.id AS user_id ,
  acc.username ,
  acc.password ,
  acc.mail ,
  usrsts.is_logged_in
  ...
FROM
  generel.account AS acc 
  INNER JOIN
    game.userstatus AS usrsts 
    ON acc.id = usrsts.user_id
```

## Expected Behaviour

When selecting from the view the data the result should not be empty but depend on the where clause.
When inserting into the view the data should be redirected to both tables and be also selectable from the view.

## Problems

- cannot select from view
- can insert in view but still not select
- data will be redirected to account table but not userstatus table

As I mentioned already I'm writing a webservice for a login and the same issues persist in there as well. (I didn't check the insert thing becouse the registration happens somewhere else.)

Comment: Have you tried to just run your `SELECT` to see if it returns anything?

Comment: Pretty sure you can only update though a view to ONE table. As far as selecting though the view.... does the user loggged in have access to the game schema?  [Docs state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html): "Also, only a single table in the view definition can be updated, so the SET clause must name only columns from one of the tables in the view"

Comment: @xQbert the user im testing with is root so yes the user has every right, so basically a view is for my purpose (inserting at registration, updating at login the is_logged_in row and selecting the passwort for comparison when logging in) is useless?
how would you approach this when registration takes place at a webfrontend and login in the game im writing this service for?
the schemas are generel (tables used by the webfrontend and the game), game (used only by my game) and webfrontend (only used by the webfrontend). Thats why i need to join them in a view.

Comment: What else would be the purpose of a view when you cannot execute any SQLs on them? Wasting space? :)

Comment: You can select from a view; something in your setup is incorrect.  I typically attribute "Root" as the OS user; not the dtabase user; unless you created a root user account in the DB... So the user your log into the application with may not have access to the game schema; which is why you're not able to select from it.

Comment: With regards to updating though a view, if you need to update multiple tables that's what stored procedures are for.

Comment: i created a database user for my application and each request from the application is coming from this user. it got access rights on those 3 schemas and all required access rights on the tables (even delete)